# Not accepting questions from my account

Tags: support

I asked 6 questions with my account. The first two questions were down voted and closed. But I was able to use my account and I asked more 4 questions. These 4 questions weren't up voted but neither down voted, and they're all still open. Now I see that after two weeks from my last closed question I am not able anymore to ask questions. I don't think that I deserve to be blocked from asking questions, would someone explain this?

Comment: Are you answer blocked, or question blocked? The title would say answers, but your question body says questions.

Comment: Questions are blocked, it was a typing mistake.

Comment: Okay. Two closed, downvoted questions shoudln't trigger the question filter. Hopefully a mod can shed some light, do you have any deleted questions (i.e. deleted by yourself?)

Comment: Now I am able to ask questions, after some of you up voted that 4 questions.

Comment: You also have a deleted question. They might have tightened up the low-quality filters recently, I'm not sure. But the message saying that you could no longer ask questions clearly gives link with all the information you need. I don't mean to be offensive, but there were only two sentences in the message and you apparently ignored one of them completely.

Comment: @ChrisS I haven't ignored the message, I copy-pasted the link and read the content, I just couldn't believe that I was banned from asking questions at that time, even if my last "bad" question was 2 weeks ago, and I didn't remember about the other deleted question.